Header file errors
I am new to MPLABx harmony and getting this error even after adding these header files. So how to remove this error?
I am performing this task in linux.
make -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/Drive_IN_WD_1/neha/harmony_project/firmware/test_harmony_1.X'
make  -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk dist/default/production/test_harmony_1.X.production.hex
make[2]: Entering directory '/Drive_IN_WD_1/neha/harmony_project/firmware/test_harmony_1.X'
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/xc32-gcc"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=LAN9255ZMX020  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/530872559/interrupts.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/530872559/interrupts.o ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/interrupts.c    -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/Microchip/LAN9255_DFP/1.3.20" -I "/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.8.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/xc32-gcc"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=LAN9255ZMX020  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/468224891/plib_cmcc.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/468224891/plib_cmcc.o ../src/config/samd51_lan9253_evb/peripheral/cmcc/plib_cmcc.c    -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/Microchip/LAN9255_DFP/1.3.20" -I "/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.8.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/xc32-gcc"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=LAN9255ZMX020  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/530872559/startup_xc32.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/530872559/startup_xc32.o ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/startup_xc32.c    -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/Microchip/LAN9255_DFP/1.3.20" -I "/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.8.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/xc32-gcc"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=LAN9255ZMX020  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/530872559/libc_syscalls.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/530872559/libc_syscalls.o ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/libc_syscalls.c    -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/Microchip/LAN9255_DFP/1.3.20" -I "/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.8.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/xc32-gcc"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=LAN9255ZMX020  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/1884831521/drv_lan9253_ecat_util.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/1884831521/drv_lan9253_ecat_util.o ../src/config/samd51_lan9253_evb/driver/lan9253/drv_lan9253_ecat_util.c    -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/Microchip/LAN9255_DFP/1.3.20" -I "/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.8.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/xc32-gcc"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=LAN9255ZMX020  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/1681782237/plib_cmcc.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/1681782237/plib_cmcc.o ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/cmcc/plib_cmcc.c    -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/Microchip/LAN9255_DFP/1.3.20" -I "/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.8.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/xc32-gcc"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=LAN9255ZMX020  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/1261449928/drv_lan9252.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/1261449928/drv_lan9252.o ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/driver/lan9252/drv_lan9252.c    -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/Microchip/LAN9255_DFP/1.3.20" -I "/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.8.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/xc32-gcc"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=LAN9255ZMX020  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/1884831521/drv_lan9253.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/1884831521/drv_lan9253.o ../src/config/samd51_lan9253_evb/driver/lan9253/drv_lan9253.c    -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/Microchip/LAN9255_DFP/1.3.20" -I "/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.8.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/xc32-gcc"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=LAN9255ZMX020  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/597773129/plib_evsys.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/597773129/plib_evsys.o ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/evsys/plib_evsys.c    -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/Microchip/LAN9255_DFP/1.3.20" -I "/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.8.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/xc32-gcc"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=LAN9255ZMX020  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/1682118773/plib_nvic.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/1682118773/plib_nvic.o ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/nvic/plib_nvic.c    -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/Microchip/LAN9255_DFP/1.3.20" -I "/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.8.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/xc32-gcc"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=LAN9255ZMX020  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/1630087885/plib_clock.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/1630087885/plib_clock.o ../src/config/samd51_lan9253_evb/peripheral/clock/plib_clock.c    -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/Microchip/LAN9255_DFP/1.3.20" -I "/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.8.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/xc32-gcc"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=LAN9255ZMX020  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/1682171924/plib_port.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/1682171924/plib_port.o ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/port/plib_port.c    -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/Microchip/LAN9255_DFP/1.3.20" -I "/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.8.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/xc32-gcc"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=LAN9255ZMX020  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/1033740028/sys_int.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/1033740028/sys_int.o ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/system/int/src/sys_int.c    -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/Microchip/LAN9255_DFP/1.3.20" -I "/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.8.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/xc32-gcc"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=LAN9255ZMX020  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/530872559/exceptions.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/530872559/exceptions.o ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/exceptions.c    -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/Microchip/LAN9255_DFP/1.3.20" -I "/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.8.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/xc32-gcc"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=LAN9255ZMX020  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/530872559/tasks.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/530872559/tasks.o ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/tasks.c    -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/Microchip/LAN9255_DFP/1.3.20" -I "/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.8.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/xc32-gcc"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=LAN9255ZMX020  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/1439726156/plib_eic.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/1439726156/plib_eic.o ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/eic/plib_eic.c    -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/Microchip/LAN9255_DFP/1.3.20" -I "/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.8.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/xc32-gcc"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=LAN9255ZMX020  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/1261449928/drv_lan9252_ecat_util.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/1261449928/drv_lan9252_ecat_util.o ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/driver/lan9252/drv_lan9252_ecat_util.c    -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/Microchip/LAN9255_DFP/1.3.20" -I "/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.8.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/xc32-gcc"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=LAN9255ZMX020  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/595623643/plib_clock.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/595623643/plib_clock.o ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/clock/plib_clock.c    -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/Microchip/LAN9255_DFP/1.3.20" -I "/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.8.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/xc32-gcc"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=LAN9255ZMX020  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/1674234083/plib_nvmctrl.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/1674234083/plib_nvmctrl.o ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/nvmctrl/plib_nvmctrl.c    -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/Microchip/LAN9255_DFP/1.3.20" -I "/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.8.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/xc32-gcc"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=LAN9255ZMX020  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/1682205486/plib_qspi_spi.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/1682205486/plib_qspi_spi.o ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/qspi/plib_qspi_spi.c    -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/Microchip/LAN9255_DFP/1.3.20" -I "/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.8.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/xc32-gcc"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=LAN9255ZMX020  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/1439758985/plib_systick.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/1439758985/plib_systick.o ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/systick/plib_systick.c    -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/Microchip/LAN9255_DFP/1.3.20" -I "/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.8.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/xc32-gcc"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=LAN9255ZMX020  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/1061935422/plib_tc0.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/1061935422/plib_tc0.o ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/tc/plib_tc0.c    -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/Microchip/LAN9255_DFP/1.3.20" -I "/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.8.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/xc32-gcc"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=LAN9255ZMX020  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/530872559/initialization.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/530872559/initialization.o ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/initialization.c    -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/Microchip/LAN9255_DFP/1.3.20" -I "/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.8.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
"/opt/microchip/xc32/v4.00/bin/xc32-gcc"    -g -x c -c -mprocessor=LAN9255ZMX020  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -O1 -fno-common -Werror -Wall -MP -MMD -MF "build/default/production/_ext/2063107748/plib_eic.o.d" -o build/default/production/_ext/2063107748/plib_eic.o ../src/config/samd51_lan9253_evb/peripheral/eic/plib_eic.c    -DXPRJ_default=default      -mdfp="/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/Microchip/LAN9255_DFP/1.3.20" -I "/home/inspirelab4/.mchp_packs/ARM/CMSIS/5.8.0/CMSIS/Core/Include" 
../src/config/samd51_lan9253_evb/peripheral/cmcc/plib_cmcc.c:41:10: fatal error: device.h: No such file or directory
 #include "device.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:844: build/default/production/_ext/468224891/plib_cmcc.o] Error 255
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/cmcc/plib_cmcc.c:41:10: fatal error: device.h: No such file or directory
 #include "device.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:724: build/default/production/_ext/1681782237/plib_cmcc.o] Error 255
In file included from ../src/config/samd51_lan9253_evb/driver/lan9253/drv_lan9253_ecat_util.c:46:
../src/config/samd51_lan9253_evb/driver/lan9253/drv_lan9253.h:51:10: fatal error: esc.h: No such file or directory
 #include "esc.h"
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:832: build/default/production/_ext/1884831521/drv_lan9253_ecat_util.o] Error 255
In file included from ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/nvmctrl/plib_nvmctrl.c:51:
../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/nvmctrl/plib_nvmctrl.h:53:10: fatal error: device.h: No such file or directory
 #include "device.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:748: build/default/production/_ext/1674234083/plib_nvmctrl.o] Error 255
../src/config/samd51_lan9253_evb/driver/lan9253/drv_lan9253.c:47:10: fatal error: ecat_def.h: No such file or directory
 #include "ecat_def.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/driver/lan9252/drv_lan9252.c:47:10: fatal error: ecat_def.h: No such file or directory
 #include "ecat_def.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:826: build/default/production/_ext/1884831521/drv_lan9253.o] Error 255
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:706: build/default/production/_ext/1261449928/drv_lan9252.o] Error 255
In file included from ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/libc_syscalls.c:30:
../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/device.h:60:10: fatal error: samd51j19a.h: No such file or directory
 #include "samd51j19a.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:808: build/default/production/_ext/530872559/libc_syscalls.o] Error 255
In file included from ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/startup_xc32.c:29:
../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/device.h:60:10: fatal error: samd51j19a.h: No such file or directory
 #include "samd51j19a.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/evsys/plib_evsys.c:41:
../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/evsys/plib_evsys.h:44:10: fatal error: device.h: No such file or directory
 #include "device.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/definitions.h:51,
                 from ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/initialization.c:46:
../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/qspi/plib_qspi_spi.h:57:10: fatal error: device.h: No such file or directory
 #include "device.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:736: build/default/production/_ext/597773129/plib_evsys.o] Error 255
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:814: build/default/production/_ext/530872559/startup_xc32.o] Error 255
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:796: build/default/production/_ext/530872559/initialization.o] Error 255
../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/nvic/plib_nvic.c:41:10: fatal error: device.h: No such file or directory
 #include "device.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:742: build/default/production/_ext/1682118773/plib_nvic.o] Error 255
../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/system/int/src/sys_int.c:53:10: fatal error: system/int/sys_int.h: No such file or directory
 #include "system/int/sys_int.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:784: build/default/production/_ext/1033740028/sys_int.o] Error 255
In file included from ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/definitions.h:51,
                 from ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/exceptions.c:48:
../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/qspi/plib_qspi_spi.h:57:10: fatal error: device.h: No such file or directory
 #include "device.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:790: build/default/production/_ext/530872559/exceptions.o] Error 255
In file included from ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/definitions.h:51,
                 from ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/interrupts.c:54:
../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/qspi/plib_qspi_spi.h:57:10: fatal error: device.h: No such file or directory
 #include "device.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:802: build/default/production/_ext/530872559/interrupts.o] Error 255
In file included from ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/driver/lan9252/drv_lan9252_ecat_util.c:46:
../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/driver/lan9252/drv_lan9252.h:51:10: fatal error: esc.h: No such file or directory
 #include "esc.h"
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:712: build/default/production/_ext/1261449928/drv_lan9252_ecat_util.o] Error 255
../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/systick/plib_systick.c:41:10: fatal error: device.h: No such file or directory
 #include "device.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/tc/plib_tc0.c:56:10: fatal error: interrupts.h: No such file or directory
 #include "interrupts.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:766: build/default/production/_ext/1439758985/plib_systick.o] Error 255
In file included from ../src/config/samd51_lan9253_evb/peripheral/eic/plib_eic.c:56:
../src/config/samd51_lan9253_evb/peripheral/eic/plib_eic.h:58:10: fatal error: device.h: No such file or directory
 #include "device.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:850: build/default/production/_ext/2063107748/plib_eic.o] Error 255
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:772: build/default/production/_ext/1061935422/plib_tc0.o] Error 255
../src/config/samd51_lan9253_evb/peripheral/clock/plib_clock.c:42:10: fatal error: device.h: No such file or directory
 #include "device.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:838: build/default/production/_ext/1630087885/plib_clock.o] Error 255
../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/clock/plib_clock.c:42:10: fatal error: device.h: No such file or directory
 #include "device.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:718: build/default/production/_ext/595623643/plib_clock.o] Error 255
In file included from ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/qspi/plib_qspi_spi.c:44:
../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/qspi/plib_qspi_spi.h:57:10: fatal error: device.h: No such file or directory
 #include "device.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:760: build/default/production/_ext/1682205486/plib_qspi_spi.o] Error 255
In file included from ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/eic/plib_eic.c:56:
../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/eic/plib_eic.h:58:10: fatal error: device.h: No such file or directory
 #include "device.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/port/plib_port.c:48:
../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/peripheral/port/plib_port.h:51:10: fatal error: device.h: No such file or directory
 #include "device.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:730: build/default/production/_ext/1439726156/plib_eic.o] Error 255
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:754: build/default/production/_ext/1682171924/plib_port.o] Error 255
../src/config/sam_d51_lan9252_evb/tasks.c:53:10: fatal error: configuration.h: No such file or directory
 #include "configuration.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:820: build/default/production/_ext/530872559/tasks.o] Error 255
make[1]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:94: .build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: .build-impl] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/Drive_IN_WD_1/neha/harmony_project/firmware/test_harmony_1.X'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/Drive_IN_WD_1/neha/harmony_project/firmware/test_harmony_1.X'

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)

